# make ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated to stop throwing the error and just returning false/true value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test. I use the code below to see if an element is invisible or not and I am expecting it to return false when it is visible and true when it is invisible:

```
  boolean b = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath("//div[@class='bla bla']")));
```

but it throws `Timed out after 2 seconds waiting for element to no longer be visible` when the element is visible, how can I make `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated` to stop throwing the error and just returning false/true value?

Comment: Are you sure the `//div[@class='bla bla']` locator matches the desired element and this is the only element matching the locator? Please provide the HTML code of the page.

Comment: @alecxe yes this the unique element and sorry I am not permitted to provide the html :(

Comment: I write in c#, but couldn't you wrap it in a try/catch and if it throws the exception type you'e receiving now, set the boolean to true?

Comment: @DerreckDean yes I solved it by using`code` and `catch` but I wonder why we couldn't use `invisibilityOfElementLocated`, what is that boolean that it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose it's better to use [isDisplayed](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed()) method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='bla bla']"));
Boolean displayed = element.isDisplayed();
System.out.print(displayed);
```

And make sure you are using right selector. Don't confuse css selectors and xpath.

---

If you really want to ignore exception and use [invisibilityOfElementLocated](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method try:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[class='bla bla']"));
```

Note: instead of `NoSuchElementException` type you can put any type of exception which you want to ignore.

Comment: so what is that boolean that **invisibilityOfElementLocated** returns ?

Comment: I have a question, Does this code: `Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
    .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);` mean that if I use this wait to click on a button, it will do it every 5 seconds for total 60 second as long as there is no error thrown ?

Comment: I'll try to answer, but if you want to get the further information take a look at the docs or ask new question ;-) `withTimeout` means it will try to satisfy your condition (like wait till visible) during this period of time, if condition is not satisfied a timeout exception will be thrown. `pollingEvery` means your condition will be executed every N seconds (aka interval between execution of your condition).

Comment: so long story short, it clicks on the button every 5 seconds till no error is thrown or 60 seconds is over, right?

Comment: This thing is basically used for waiting; not for repetitive tasks/actions; however what you said it's possible to implement using custom implementation of `ExpectedConditions`

Comment: @LoveJavaTwo take a look for the common use cases of custom implementations of `ExpectedConditions`: https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/com/wikia/webdriver/common/core/CommonExpectedConditions.java